# .net core Web Page not routing to inherited class with OnGet() method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

How do I re-direct it to the OnGet() method in the correct class?

I have code implemented something like the below where I have a base page class and a reports page class that inherited from the base page. During runtime, the startup route is suppose to load http://localhost:xxxx/Reporting. However, the code in the reporting class is not executed including the OnGet() Method. Instead it tries to run the BasePage OnGet() method.

Shared\Components\BasePage\index.cshtml.cs

```
namespace Reporting.Web.Pages.Reports
{
    [TypeFilter(typeof(RouteAccessAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { @"/BasePage/Index" })]
    public class BasePageModel : PageModel
    {
        public readonly ILogger<BasePageModel> _logger;

        public BasePageModel(
            ILogger<BasePageModel> logger,
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public bool GenerateReport { get; set; }

        public ActionResult OnGet()
        {
            return RedirectToPage("/Status/Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Reporting\index.cshtml.cs

```
namespace Reporting.Web.Pages.Reports
{
    [TypeFilter(typeof(RouteAccessAttribute), Arguments = new object[] { @"/Report/Index" })]
    public class IndexModel : BasePageModel
    {
        public IndexModel(
            ILogger<IndexModel> logger) : base(logger)
        {
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGet()
        {
            var clientId = HttpContext.Session.Get<int>("ClientId");

            if (clientId > 0)
            {
                Client = HttpContext.Session.Get<IEnumerable<Client>>("Clients").Where(x => x.Id.Equals(clientId)).FirstOrDefault();

                return Page();
            }

            return RedirectToPage("/Status/Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I have the opposite issue with the view, it runs Reporting\index.cshtml but I would instead like to have it run common code under BasePage\index.cshtml.

Comment: Hi @Bill, firstly, not sure what is your `RouteAccessAttrite` here and cannot reproduce the redirect to the BasePage. It will give the error:`Multiple handlers matched.`. The correct way use the implements is add the `virtual` for the OnGet of BasePageModel, then add the `override` for the OnGet of `IndexModel`. What do you mean for the last sentence of running conmon code under BasePage/Index.cshtml? It seems you do not understand how razor pages find, it find by the folder name and page name. e.g If contains `BasePage/Index.cshtml`, it will get into the `IndexModel` in Pages/BasePage folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance doesn't really work with ASP.NET Core.